# Box2D Body type

Tags: box2d

I need to design a special block in box2d which is not affected by any forces but if the player stays on it for a set amount of time, it should fall down with gravitational acceleration (g = 9.8 m/s^2 on Earth). I don't know which body type to use or how to code it. Static body does not move under forces, kinematic body moves only with set velocity, and dynamic body moves under any force which means that the player can move it by bumping it.

Comment: You can use mask bits and filter bits so that the collision doesn't register for different types. To be able to know when they overlap though, you need to iterate through all collisions using contact listener, in jbox, anyhow

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to reset the body type once the player stays on this body for the set amount of time.

The body can initially be static, then set to dynamic for it to fall according to the gravity:

```
// body creation
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
b2Body* body = world.CreateBody(&bodyDef);

// if the player stayed long enough on it
body->SetType(b2_dynamicBody);
```